# Which version of SSIS track versions of SSIS Package deployed to Server?

Tags: ssis

Which version of SSIS track versions of SSIS Package deployed to Server ? Please provide version.

Comment: Could you please restate your question? It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

DTS (very old version of SSIS) used to do it automatically. But as far as I know no versions of SSIS do it. You use TFS for that, but it just manages all the source code.

Answer (score 0):

To check the package format version you have to open .dtsx file itself .
If PackageFormatVersion>3 then its 2008 when PackageFormatVersion>6 then its 2012 and when PackageFormatVersion>8 then 2014.
I have added snapshot it might help you to understand how to check version in SSIS.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSIS 2012, 2014 and 2017 can track versions of SSIS Package deployed to Server. SSIS 2005, 2008 did not have this features.